# Implementing ILocationListener without specific Activity at Xamarin.Android app

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, location-services

I have implemented singletone service which processes all location change events.

```
public class LocationService : ILocationListener 
{
        public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
        }

        public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider)
        {
        }

        public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider)
        {
        }

        public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, Availability status, Bundle extras)
        {
        }
}
```

But now, when I separate this service from activity it asks me to implement two more methods, which I'm not sure how to handle in my case:

```
public IntPtr Handle
{
    get { ... }
}

public void Dispose()
{
}
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inherit from Java.Lang.Object and you are good to go.